# Plugins Qgis repositry

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

i tried to install the last version of Qgis (Version 3.0), i removed the Users.qgis folder, the installation was succefelly executed.

i used plugins Builder to create a new plugin but it's failed cause of the path doesn't found

how should i create the .qgis files to create new plugins again?

i tried to unstall completly Qgis and instal it again but the .qgis folder does not appear.

Comment: Do you have any official QGIS3 plugin installed? AFAIK the destination folder is now somewhere else.

Comment: I think the destination folder has been moved to: `C:/Users/You/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins`

Comment: Thanks for your help, i installed an offcial plugin of QGIS3, i have searched for the path, now im using the path found and  its work correctly